# Fastlane: How can I "increment_build_number" of one target only?

Tags: ios, fastlane

I have two targets in my Xcode project:

1. MyAwesomeApp (build 1)
2. MyGreatApp (build 1)

After the increment_build_number action, they both turn to:

1. MyAwesomeApp (build 2)
2. MyGreatApp (build 2)

But what I expect is to apply it to only one target. So when I execute something like this one more time:
`increment_builder_number(scheme: "MyAwesomeAppScheme")`

They turn to:

1. MyAwesomeApp (build 3)
2. MyGreatApp (build 2) <-- This build number should be unchanged

Is there a way to achieve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have created my custom lane that by using "xcodeproj" is able to set both the version and the build number for a specific target name.

```
# Sets the "VERSION" and "BUILD" number for a target
#
# @param args [Hash] Key value arguments. All the values are Strings. List: 
#   - target_name: The name of the target (REQUIRED)
#   - version: The version number to be used (REQUIRED)
#   - build: The build number to be used (REQUIRED)
#
desc "Sets the \"VERSION\" and \"BUILD\" number for a target"
lane :set_version_build_number do |args|
    puts("\"set_version_build_number\" lane with ARGUMENTS: #{args}")

    target_name = args[:target_name]
    version = args[:version]
    build = args[:build]

    raise(StandardError, "Invalid ARGUMENTS for: \"set_version_build_number\" LANE") unless (
        target_name != nil &&
        version != nil &&
        build != nil
    )

    puts("Variables:")
    puts("\ttarget_name: #{target_name}")
    puts("\tversion: #{version}")
    puts("\tbuild: #{build}")
    
    project_url = find_xcode_project()
    raise(StandardError, "Invalid Xcode project for: \"set_version_build_number\" LANE") unless project_url != nil
    project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_url)

    xc_target = project.targets.find { |target| target.name == target_name }
    raise(StandardError, "Invalid target for: \"set_version_build_number\" LANE") unless xc_target != nil

    xc_target.build_configurations.each { |build_configuration| 
        build_configuration.build_settings["MARKETING_VERSION"] = version
        build_configuration.build_settings["CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION"] = build
    }

    project.save()
end
```

Where:

```
# Finds the location for an Xcode project within the current directory and all his parents
#
# @return [String] Full path to the Xcode project or nil if unsuccess
#
def find_xcode_project ()
    absolute_dir_path = Dir.getwd
    loop do
        entries = Dir.entries(absolute_dir_path)
        index = entries.find_index{ |entry| entry.include?(".xcodeproj") }
        if index != nil
          return "#{absolute_dir_path}/#{entries[index]}"
        end
  
        absolute_dir_path = File.dirname(absolute_dir_path)
        if absolute_dir_path == nil || absolute_dir_path == "/"
          break
        end
    end
  
    return nil
end
```

It can easily be used:

```
bundle exec fastlane set_version_build_number target_name:TargetApp version:2.0 build:3
```

Of course don't forget to add this into the Fastlane file:

```
require "xcodeproj"
```

and this into the Gemfile

```
gem "xcodeproj"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've modified and updated this to increment an existing build number instead of having to pass it in. Also removed the setting of the marketing version number.


For anyone interested it is here:
https://gist.github.com/gdavis/6b594e98ec99ea9ee51d937264d80382

Answer (score 10):

Here is a [plug-in](https://github.com/SiarheiFedartsou/fastlane-plugin-versioning) to increment the build number.

This is what it looks like in the Fastfile:

```
increment_build_number_in_plist(        
   target:"MyAwesomeApp"
)
```

Comment: Don't forget that for now there is no support for plugins with `Faslane.swift` :(

Comment: For newer Xcode projects, you might need to add `plist_build_setting_support: true` setting to the action for it to work. It is required when build number isn't stored in the plist but in the Build Settings instead.

Answer (score 5):

I could easily add this option to the `fastlane` action, but would need the `agvtool` equivalent for doing that. The `increment_build_number` step is mostly a wrapper around `agvtool`.

You can find more information on Apple's Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/agvtool.1.html

Comment: Please take a look at @NSCabezon's suggestion

Answer (score 2):

And what about specifying as a parameter the .plist file you want to bump?? something like:

```
plist_path: "./Info.plist"
```

Comment: But hmm the actions has no parameter named plist_path, right? https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/increment_build_number.rb